# PHP Red Bean Not returning correct result

Tags: php, mysql, orm, redbean

I have 3 tables.

Episode,
Season,
Episode_Season

I have made a view as such

```
"CREATE VIEW episode_season_view AS SELECT * FROM episode
INNER JOIN episode_season ON episode.id = episode_season.episode_id
INNER JOIN season ON season.id = episode_season.season_id";
```

Which btw works like a charm...
Now when I run this query in MysqlWorkbench

```
"SELECT * FROM season_episode_view
WHERE first_aired > CURDATE() AND season_id = 600";
```

it returns the correct result.
But when i do this,

```
R::getRow("SELECT * FROM season_episode_view
WHERE first_aired > ? AND season_id = ?", array(date('Y-m-d'), $season_id));
```

it returns 0 rows... and I cant understand why?

Comment: if i turn the > sign the other way as < it gives me the oldest date tho... but not the other way around. even tho there is a newer date then today's date, as mysqlworkbenche returns 1 result with the same query

Comment: Is your date in the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but rather than using PHP's date functions, use Redbean's MySQL functions and possibly `getAll()`:

```
$results=R::getAll("SELECT * FROM season_episode_view 
WHERE first_aired > ? AND season_id = ?", array(R::$f->curdate(), $season_id));
```

If that doesn't work, you can try the built in querying:

```
$row=R::$f->begin()
  ->select('*')->from('season_episode_view')
  ->where(' first_aired > ? AND season_id = ?')->put(R::$f->curdate(),$season_id)
  ->get('row');
```

Only other thing I can think of is that the `first_aired` column doesn't like PHP's `date()` for some reason, possibly due to the field type?

Comment: This is 3.2+ only I believe.  Older versions may not support the `$f` functions or the new select syntax.

Comment: getAll worked exactly like getRow, except it got all the episodes before todays date and none for newer by changing the < > operator.
Also i didnt get R::$f->begin() to return anything at all, and I got version 3.2+

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  Try `R::find('season_episode_view','first_aired > ? AND season_id = ?',array(R::$f->curdate(),$season_id));`

Comment: If that doesn't work, then really, it is your table/view.  Why not skip trying to query the view and just use the join statement in your query?

Comment: I have tried that as well, and i have made a procedure, both with no luck. I don't get this. totally weird :P